# Regex for parse YAML

Tags: regex, yaml

I have many translation files organized in YAML files. For example:

```yaml
    every_month: Kas mėnesį
    bank_acc_nr: A/s
    'Internal Server Error': 'Vidinė serverio klaida'
    next_lock: 'Kitas užrakinimas'
    two_days_later_00:00: Two days later 00:00
    same_day_00:00: 'Tą pačia dieną 00:00'
    'series %number%': 'Serija: Nr. %number%'
    not_allowed_to_edit_records_before_reset_date: 'Neleidžiama kurti įrašų anksčiau archyvo datos: %date%'
```

After upgrade, my framework requires that I add quotes to all translation messages. To do it by the hands will be a very long and complex task. I've tried to write next regex for this `(.*?):[\s]{0,2}([^'"]{0,1}[\%]?[\w\d]+[\%]?[\/,\-\.\(\)\%\_\h\p{L}]+)`, and it has a little bug, it also matches lines like these:

```yaml
    'series %number%': 'Serija: Nr. %number%'
    not_allowed_to_edit_records_before_reset_date: 'Neleidžiama kurti įrašų anksčiau archyvo datos: %date%'
```

but I want only to match lines without quotes:

```yaml
    every_month: Kas mėnesį
    bank_acc_nr: A/s
    two_days_later_00:00: Two days later 00:00
```

Here is an online regex editor where I tried to implement that https://regex101.com/r/t5hRAk/2

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(.*?):\s{1,2}(?!['"])((?:%\w+%|\w+)[\/,\-.()_\h\p{L}:\d]+)$` https://regex101.com/r/l92jUf/1

Comment: @The fourth bird, yes, it's exactly what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add matching a `:` and digits `\d` to the last character class and  match 1-2 whitespace chars after the colon and use anchors `^` and `$`

```
^(.*?):\s{1,2}(%?\w+%?[\/,.()_\h\p{L}:\d-]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1KQ736/1)

About the pattern you tried

- `[\%]?` can be written as `%?`
- `\w` also matches `\d`, so this `[\w\d]+` can be written as `\w+`
- If the value should be between % or neither you could write `%?\w+%?` as `(?:%\w+%|\w+)`
- It depends on the delimiters, but you don't have to escape the `\/`

---

If you want to match any char except `"` or `'` before the first optional `%`:

```
^(.*?):\s{1,2}([^'"]?%?\w+%?[\/,.()_\h\p{L}:\d-]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ctEZp1/1)

Comment: As I see, my regex also works, but I forgot about anchors `^` and `$`. Anyway, many thanks.